# .htaccess redirect to https://www. with exception of subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, subdomain

I need to redirect non www request to www. I also need to redirect http requests to https. furthermore, I need the mail subdomain not to be redirected at all.

I've got the following code on my Magento site .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

In my limited understanding, the following line is redirecting all requests to https://www.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I need to add an exception so that the mail subdomain is no redirected to https://www. A request like mail.example.com should not be redirected at all.

Can you help me achieve this?